# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores de un array y remplazarlo por una posición especifica en Java?

Tags: java

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio lo cual consiste de sumar el primer número y último de un Arreglo, lo cuál la cantidad del arreglo es N. Luego de ello, la suma de esos dos números tendrá que ser remplazado por el número mayor ingresado en el mismo Arreglo.

Ejemplo de un Arreglo N = 4:
[5, 10, 80, 25]
Suma del primero y último: 30
El númer 30 remplazará el número mayor ingresado: 80
Resultado: [5, 10, 30, 25]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables
   int datos[], N, mayor, posicion_mayor, suma=0;
   // Ler N elementos de un vector
    System.out.print("Ingres el tamaño del Vector (N): ");
    N = lectura.nextInt();
    datos = new int[N];  
    for(int i=0; i<datos.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para datos["+i+"] = ");
        datos[i] = lectura.nextInt();
    }
    //Encontrar el mayor y su posición
        mayor = datos[0];
        posicion_mayor = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<datos.length; i++){
            if(datos[i]>mayor){
                mayor=datos[i];
                posicion_mayor=i;
            }
        }
        // Sumar el primer número y último, luego remplazarlo con el número mayor
        for(int i = posicion_mayor+1; i< datos.length; i++){
            suma = suma + datos[i]; //Intento erroneo.
        }
        //Remplazar el elemento mayor con la suma
        datos[posicion_mayor] = suma;
        // Imprimir en pantalla el vector actualizado evidenciado los cambios
        System.out.println("\nEl mayor es "+mayor+" esta en la posición "+posicion_mayor+
                            "\nLa suma del primer número y último es : "+suma);
        System.out.println("\nLos datos del vector actualizado son : ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i< datos.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Valor de datos["+i+"] = "+datos[i]);
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias por su apoyo, espero su pronta ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas intentando una suma acumulativa

```
 // Sumar el primer número y último, luego remplazarlo con el número mayor
        for(int i = posicion_mayor+1; i< datos.length; i++){
            suma = suma + datos[i]; //Intento erroneo.
        }
```

si quieres obtener la suma del primero y el ultimo numero en el array,esto lo podes conseguir apartir de los índices como todos empiezan en 0

primer índice =      0

ultimo índice =      el tamaño del arreglo -1

```
suma = datos[0] + datos[datos.length-1];
```